# Не работает скрипт включенный в html документ

Tags: javascript, html

Есть html документ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('Nein Nein Nein!');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Пишу я перед `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Nein Nein Nein!');
</script>
```

Но он не работает, а если выношу его в отдельный документ, то начинает работать

`<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Консоль в браузере пишет:

> Загрузка  по адресу
>   «file:///jscript-load/2100f48273017b3834.js» не удалась.

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Удали src у скрипта?

Comment: Что то Вы не договариваете, явно скрипт не выполняется из-за того что произошла ошибка, которую, впрочем, Вам браузер и показывает. То, что Вы здесь показали явно не соответствует тому, что Вы пытаетесь выполнить. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, внимательно на свой текст страницы.

Answer (score -1):

Попытайтесь отключить блокировщик объявлений / сценариев. Может у вас есть adblock?

Comment: Блокировщик действительно был, но в выключенном состоянии, удалил ничего не изменилось. А еще,  внешне скрипты перестают работать если я помещаю их в какое-либо другое место, кроме перед концом `</body>`